# Fortran: how can double precision variable read and hold string content from an input file

Tags: fortran90, fortran77

I'm converting a rather large old fix-format code written in Fortran 77 to free-format. Within the code I frequently encounter read statements like

```
DOUBLE PRECISION :: VARIABLE

read(1,10) VARIABLE

10 format(2A10)
```

However, what it reads from input file is in fact a line of string. The code runs perfectly fine, but it crashes when one tries to read VARIABLE from a namelist instead of a fixed format input file.

How is this possible in Fortran? Is there any reference where I can find more information about?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: the :: indicates that someone has already (attempted to) update this to modern standards. Do you have the actual origial code? Did they originally use namelists or are you trying to introduce that? Personally i find namelists a nonportable mess and would get rid of their usage unless its really entrenched in the old code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This comes from the days before F77 when doubles and integers were used for storing characters.  From the format statement, this is probably from a CDC which could store 10 six bit characters in each word.  Double precision was two words so it was two lots of 10 characters.  If you change the code to

```
CHARACTER(LEN=20) VARIABLE
READ(1,10) VARIABLE
10 FORMAT(A20)
```

It should work.  There isn't a lot of information about on CDC compilers.  I've never tried using a namelist with one so I can't really comment about it.  Try http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/cdc/cyber/cyber_70/chippewa/Chippewa_Fortran-Run_Apr66.pdf

Comment: i'm going to go out on a limb and say if the input is an oddball 6 bit encoded format than no way can you read it with namelist.

Comment: use a Hollerith it was made to hold characters